# How do large power supplies work? (VFD's etc.)

Tags: power-supply, power, switch-mode-power-supply

I've looked at the designs of switching power supplies (buck/boost/buck-boost) and I basically understand how they work. But is this the same thing used in large power supplies such as those in the VFD of a tower crane (etc.)? Like the larger of the two hoist winches offered for the Liebherr 710 HCL 25/50 tower crane, which uses a 220 kW (294 H.P.) AC motor. How does the power supply maintain DC output while the motor is bogged out to ~18% of full speed?** Do large VFD's and whatnot still use a conventional buck (boost) switching converter to get the required "rail voltage"?

Note that 480 Vrms coming in gets you approx. 680 VDC through the rectifier and reservoir capacitors.

**Here's part of the performance data if anyone wants to know:

0 - 3450 kg*** at 0 - 238 m/min (0 - 6900 kg at 0 - 119 m/min)

0 - 25000 kg at 0 - 43 m/min (0 - 50000 kg at 0 - 22 m/min)

***238 m/min only goes up to 1800 kg on 1-part line if the reduced speed curve is used.

Comment: Google AC drive. You can scale it up to as high power as you would like given enough rating on your transistors, inductors and capacitors.

Comment: I'm wondering how the Power Supply Unit maintains a steady rail voltage. I mostly understand how the speed control circuits work.

Comment: What if the DC rail voltage was not kept absolutely constant ? To keep it constant under all load conditions would require a lot from the DC regulator (assuming there is one ! Is there ?) What if there was no regulation so the voltage would vary under load. How would that influence the operation of the crane ? Would it still be usable ? I think it would. You're assuming a constant voltage is needed, I'm saying most motors still work at 50% of their normal operating voltage so regulation is not needed. That also saves power and makes the design simpler as well !

Comment: The piece of equipment which applies power to the winch motors is probably a VFD (Variable Frequency Drive).

Comment: Why would a tower crane have a Vacuum Florescent Display (VFD)?

Comment: Variable Frequency Drive

Comment: You don't control a rail voltage. Motor voltage is a function of speed and that one depends on the mechanical speed. And that one is a sum function of the torque. So you have to control the **current** to gain control over the torque a motor applies to the mechanics. Then control the speed by adjusting the current set-value. Then control the position by adjustion the speed set-value.

Comment: AC Motors? The Liebherr 710 HCL doesn't use DC motors.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether it is an AC motor or a DC motor. The fundamental connections are U ~ v and M ~ I. Three-phase AC motors draw contant power as a DC motor does. It's the same mechanical-electrical connection. Single phase AC motors are a bit more complicated since they cannot draw contant power. But your crane most likely doesn't use the latter apart from motor cooling fans drives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want to control a "rail voltage". You want to control **current**. Why? Because the fundamental connections between electrical and mechanical world are

$$P_\mathrm{el} = I \cdot U = M \cdot \omega = P_\mathrm{mech}$$

and, in addition:

$$U \sim \omega$$

$$M \sim I$$

It's as great as it is simple.

For your crane example this means, *depending on the load on the hook*, your motor needs a certain torque – a certain current – to keep that load at an equilibrium of constant speed.

That's why you want to measure and control the current. The current depends directly on the load applied. Speed doesn't, voltage doesn't.

Comment: So it doesn't need a complicated switching regulator to supply a 480VDC rail that supplies MOSFETs or IGBT's? Then how Liebherr can achieve "millimetric precision" is still a mystery to me. http://www.nrcan.gc.ca/sites/www.nrcan.gc.ca/files/energy/images/energystar/figure-06a.jpg

Comment: It needs an even more complicated switching regulator which controls motor **current**. Not voltage. And a speed regulator on top of that. And a position regulator on top of that.

Comment: OK. I'm starting to get it.

Comment: On some of the big VFDs that I've seen, the 480V input just goes to a SCR bridge rectifier and then a capacitor bank.

Comment: Oh. Just like a normal switching power supply where all the low frequency ripple is "chopped up" and becomes high frequency. The six transistors chop up the unregulated DC rail voltage so it doesn't really matter. And I'm assuming "SCR bridge rectifier" means an ACTIVE rectifier.

Comment: SCR means "Silicon Controlled Rectifier".